# Discrete Distribution Fitting

Tags: python, dataset, histogram, distribution, discrete

I have a dataset in xlsx with some discrete values(name:saoi) and i want to see which discrete distribution fitts better to them.

I made some Histograms:

[Full Histogram]

[image: 1]

[Hist with values until 5000]

[image: 2]

[Hist with values until 10000]

[image: 3]

The code is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
   
aoi = df ["social AoI"]
saoi = pd.Series(aoi).array
saoi = np.around(saoi)
saoi = saoi.astype(int)

h = plt.hist(saoi)
plt.title('Hist of Social AoI')
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Freq')
plt.axis([0,20000, 0, 200])
plt.show()
```

The values are these:

In [21]:saoi

Out[21]:
array([    0,    13,   101,   106,    10,    22,    73,    30,     1,
54,    44,     2,     4,    52,   106,    70,     1,    11,
3,    50,     2,     9,     2,    28,    32,    15,     2,
42,    53,    16,    13,    70,    12,    91,    11,    43,
18,    53,    91,     9,    52,     9,    19,    27,    18,
53,    19,   242,    19,    22,    24,    53,    90,    82,
100,    62,   111,    20,    22,     8,    41,   134,    51,
72,    10,     1,    23,     3,    32,     1,    30,    18,
164,    10,    32,    35,    65,    79,    19,    21,    37,
20,    55,    32,    75,   489,    61,   111,    54,    46,
68,    53,    12,     7,    95,    43,    48,    11,   241,
7,   295,   284,    55,    69,   223,     4,    66,   278,
33,    22,    26,   197,   117,   242,   252,    29,   325,
289,    76,    28,    84,    21,   204,    74,   189,    11,
162,    85,    35,   510,     4,   135,   299,   211,   406,
149,    99,     2,    10,  1150,   427,   337,    16,   157,
620,    95,   257,    45,   368,   428,   108,  1041,   189,
32,   246,    38,   351,   578,   151,   240,   905,   309,
7,     8,    25,   226,    22,    50,   637,    74,   825,
152,   543,  1484,   893,   524,   866,     5,   236,  1608,
387,  1038,    83,   147,  2871,  6669,  2058,   577,  1634,
2522,  4915,     9,   298,  3074,   856,    29,  7164,  1641,
1270,   143,   508,   476,  2145,  1678,  2135,    86,  1085,
4106,   967,   266,  1302, 11875,  6011,    63,  1470,  2321,
9080, 19216])

I tried to fit some discrete distribution with this code(using likelihoods):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import nbinom, poisson, geom, dlaplace, randint, yulesimon
import math
import numpy as np

x = pd.Series(saoi)
mean = x.mean()
var = x.var()
likelihoods = {}  

#nbinom
p = mean / var
r = p * mean / (1-p)
likelihoods['nbinom'] = x.map(lambda val: nbinom.pmf(val, r, p)).prod()

#poisson
lambda_ = mean
likelihoods['poisson'] = x.map(lambda val: poisson.pmf(val, lambda_)).prod()

#geometric
p = 1 / mean
likelihoods['geometric'] = x.map(lambda val: geom.pmf(val, p)).prod()

#dlaplace
a = math.sqrt(var/2)
likelihoods['dlaplace'] = x.map(lambda val: dlaplace.pmf(val, a)).prod()

#randint
low = 0
high = 242
likelihoods['randint'] = x.map(lambda val: randint.pmf(val, low, high)).prod()

#yulesimon
p = mean / (mean-1)
likelihoods['yulesimon'] = x.map(lambda val: yulesimon.pmf(val, p)).prod()

best_fit = max(likelihoods, key=lambda x: likelihoods[x])
print("Best fit:", best_fit)
print("Likelihood:", likelihoods[best_fit])
```

but the results are bad as the likelihoods are 0.

**How could i find a better fitting discrete distribution? There are many ways for continuous but what about the discrete ones?**

Comment: You could try a continuous fit and then either use its discrete analog (such as exponential => geometric, normal => binomial) or discretize it with rounding/truncation. However, a better option might be to choose a distribution based on first principles using prior knowledge of the origins of the data. Remember that all distributions are mathematical models derived from some set of assumptions. If you're unwilling or unable to make such assumptions, that leaves you with an empirical distribution, i.e., the data itself.

Comment: Knowing nothing about the origins of your data, but having briefly played with it in a stats package, I'd suggest fitting it as a discretized log-normal.

Comment: how can i discretize the continuous lognormal?

Comment: Round, ceiling, or floor.

Comment: @pjs can you tell me which stats package you used?

Comment: JMP.  I use it for teaching because it’s so interactive that students can focus on the analysis rather than how to program the analysis. Very helpful in intro courses.

Comment: @pjs do you recommend me this or another for my thesis?

Comment: @pjs i am between fitter and distfit

Comment: That's a personal choice. You can download it and try it out.

Comment: @pjs between fitter and distfit which is the best? because they give  me different results for the best fit distribution